# How to monitor what Ubuntu One is doing?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is there a way to monitor what Ubuntu One is doing when it seems to be chewing up so much network bandwidth?  I'd like to see what files it's syncing.  I looked in ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log but can't find anything that shows this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Magicicada](http://packages.ubuntu.com/magicicada). It will allow you to see what Ubuntu One is doing with a nice interface.

```
sudo apt-get install magicicada
```

[image]