# How can I watch activity of Ubuntu One?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to monitor what Ubuntu One is doing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86130/how-to-monitor-what-ubuntu-one-is-doing)

How can I watch the activity of Ubuntu One?

Is it possible to see a detailed list of uploads, downloads and so on?

Can I see a list of unsynced files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install magicicada. That shows you in detail exactly what Ubuntu One file sync is doing at any moment and what's queued up to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can see its log and see what it is doing, if you want to see the network activity you could use programs like wireshark to track the activity of a certain program

```
ls .cache/ubuntuone/log
```

The unsynced files are at:

```
more .cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon-exceptions.log
```

Comment: Thats not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a more real-time solution.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I think the OP was looking for a GUI solution, this do exactly the same thing the OP asked for, and a real time solution with this answer could be `tail -f .cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon-exceptions.log`, but the GUI sounds like a lot better answer, I would try @sil suggestion first.